# How to read CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I'm using Spyder for Python 2.7 on Windows 8. I'm trying to open and read a csv file and see all the data stored in it, but this is what I get instead:

```
runfile('C:/Users/John/Documents/Python Scripts/FLInsuraneFile.py', wdir='C:/Users/John/Documents/Python Scripts')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='FL_insurance_sample.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

How can I open the file properly?

Comment: Are you trying to read or write the file? Are you wanting to use the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module, or just print the entire contents?

Comment: @Dan Post your code related to your question?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First things first, you must understand the inner-workings of a CSV file.
CSV file are made up of rows and columns, like this:

```
| NAME  |  AGE |  ROOM |
| ---------------------|
| Kaleb |  15  |   256 |
| ---------------------|
| John  |  15  |   257 |
| ---------------------|
| Anna  |  16  |   269 |
```

Where the vertical elements are columns, and the horizontal elements are rows. Rows contain many types of data, like name/age/room. Columns contain only one type of data, like name.

Moving on, here is an example function to read the CSV.
Please carefully study the code.

```
def read_csv(csv_file):
    data = []
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:

        # create a list of rows in the CSV file
        rows = f.readlines()

        # strip white-space and newlines
        rows = list(map(lambda x:x.strip(), rows))

        for row in rows:

            # further split each row into columns assuming delimiter is comma 
            row = row.split(',')

            # append to data-frame our new row-object with columns
            data.append(row)

    return data
```

Now why would I do that? Well, this function allows you to access your CSV file by row/column. Meaning it is easier to index. Look at this example using the above function:

```
csvFile = 'test.csv'

# invoke our function 
data = read_csv(csvFile)

# get row 1, column 2 of file
print(data[1][2])

# get entirety of row 2
print(data[2])

# get row 0, columns 1 & 2
print(data[0][1], data[0][2])
```

As you can see, we can easily access different parts of the file by using our `read_csv()` function and creating a nested-list object. Finally, if you want to print to the entire file, you simply use a for loop after creating the data-object.

```
data = read_csv(csvFile)

for row in data:
    print(row)
```

In conclusion, Pandas is great for big-data science, but if you just
want to read/access the CSV, this function is just fine. No need to install big packages for little tasks, unless of course you want to :) .

Good luck!

Comment: This is *not* the correct way to parse CSV, as it would split a double-quoted value if the value contains a comma.

Answer (score 5):

You can use builtin library

```
import csv
with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pandas` library:

```
import pandas as pd
csvfile = pd.read_csv('path_to_file')
print(csvfile)
```

If you want to add custom headers to the file use the `names` argument otherwise it will just take the first row of the file as the header.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use Table Base.

```
import tablebase

My_Table = tablebase.CsvTable("path/to/your.csv")
print(My_Table.table_content)
```

For full documentation of Table Base see [python.centillionware.com/tablebase](https://python.centillionware.com/tablebase)